# Remove "Edit team project level permission ACLs" from TFS project admins so that they are not allowed to add users

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I want to restrict my TFS 2015 Update 3 (Moving to TFS 2018 shortly) project administrators, so that they are not allowed to add individual users to the TFS security groups. To add users we have in-place a custom solution where users are added to Ldap.

I have came to know from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbspproject-level) that "Edit team project level permission ACLs" permission defines the user management for the Project Administrators.

Is there a way by which I can stop the TFS team project administrators to not allow to add users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such setting to not allow to add users. I have submitted a UserVoice at website below, you can vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33317830-add-a-permission-that-not-allow-adding-users-in-tf

Comment: yeah, unfortunate, i have cast a vote for the same. marking this as answer as there is no proper answer i guess.

Comment: wanted to check, if there is a way we can trigger a script whenever someone adds a user. A web hook may be?

Comment: No, there are only WorkItem, Source Control and Build events (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/events)